# showing that the sets (Banach-Tarski-ish) which comprise $S^1$ are disjoint

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $S^1$ be the unit circle and consider $S^1 = \cup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} A_q$ where the sets $A_q$ are constructed as follows:

Define the equivalence relation $z \sim w$ if for $z = e^{i\alpha}, w = e^{i\beta}$ where $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha - \beta = \mathbb{Q}$.

Using the axiom of choice, define $A$ such that it has one representative of each equivalence class. Thus we define, $A_q = e^{iq}A = \{e^{iq}z, z\in A\}$.

I am having difficulty showing that the $A_q$'s are disjoint.

Suppose that $w \in A_q \cap A_r$. Then $\exists \, \alpha,\beta$ such that $\alpha - \beta \notin \mathbb{Q}$ with $e^{iq + i\alpha} = e^{ir + i\beta}$ or in other words, $1 = e^{i(r-q)}e^{i(\beta - \alpha)}$. Clearly, if $r-q + \beta - \alpha = 0$ for the condition to hold, we must have equality for $r,q$ and $\beta,\alpha$ because $\beta - \alpha$ is supposedly irrational yet the sum above is 0 noting that $q,r \in \mathbb{Q}$.

But what if  $r-q + \beta - \alpha = 2k\pi$? I'm having trouble with this case.

Comment: Something is wrong with your equivalence relation. It should be that $z\sim w$ if $z=e^{i\pi\alpha}$, $w=e^{i\pi\beta}$ with $\alpha-\beta\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Harald, but this is what's presented in Probability with Martingales by Williams

Comment: Ah, indeed it does. At the start of Appendix A. It's a simple mistake, easily made. The example is well known, and mistakes of that type happen when you write down well known examples. Just the fact that you know it so well means you are less careful in checking the details.